# How to set python-docx paragraph alignment to rtl

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to write a docx file using python, and I need the text to be rtl.
found some information in documentation, but for some reason it does not work..

my code:

```
import docx


doc = docx.Document()

style = doc.styles.add_style('rtl', docx.enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPES.PARAGRAPH)
style.font.rtl = True

p = doc.add_paragraph(style='rtl')
p.add_run('my rtl aligned text')

doc.save(path)
```

Comment: *but for some reason it does not work..* How so?

Comment: the alignment is still ltr when i open the file... @Kasramvd

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following instead

```
style = doc.styles.add_style('rtl', WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
```